# Training & Validation LSTM Question: Precision & Recall Issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, precision, precision-recall

I have an LSTM Encoder-Decoder model that I have developed in order to classify price movements based on the Jump-Diffusion model (binary classification problem essentially).

My model is split 75/25 between training and validation.

My issue is that after applying class imbalance techniques such as SMOTE, my model's predictive accuracy is very high across both training and validation (could be overfitting still). But, when it comes to precision, recall and f1 score my training model performs well again but on the validation side my precision and recall have declined significantly. This obviously leads to a lower f1 score on validation side.

Does anyone know why the validation accuracy would be high but the precision and recall have both declined significantly? Is this an issue with the way my model is calculating precision and recall on the validation side, or just my model is overfitting leading to lower validation results?

See image below for summary of results of model, I can also provide the notebook as well if needed.

Edit: Including Relevant Code

```
#%pip install keras-metrics

# Importing required packages
import keras_metrics as km

# LSTM Workings_Autoencoder Model

ac_model_1b = Sequential()
ac_model_1b.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=200, return_sequences = True,
                               input_shape = (n_timesteps, n_features), 
                                kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')))
ac_model_1b.add(LSTM(100))
ac_model_1b.add(Dropout(0.2))

ac_model_1b.add(RepeatVector(n_timesteps))

ac_model_1b.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences = True))
ac_model_1b.add(Dropout(0.2))
ac_model_1b.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences = True))
ac_model_1b.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))

ac_model_1b.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adamax', 
                 metrics=['accuracy', km.binary_precision(), km.binary_recall()])

results_ac_model_1b = ac_model_1b.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32,
                        shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid))

print(ac_model_1b.summary())

ac_model_1b.save('lstm_model_adamax.h5')
```

[image]

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: It might not seem that way but it is, the package I used to calculate the precision and recall is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It could be better if you could give your confusion matrix.**

But, it seems something is wrong with the calc.

[image: accuracy]

[image: Precision]

[image: Recall]

mathematically, **(accuracy + recall >= precision)

edited:
Here goes the [mathematical identity](https://qr.ae/pN2u3K).

In your case, 31 + 33 < 97

I would suggest you to use [this function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html). And get the report, I would appreciate if you can print it's output in the question.

Comment: I've added the code I used, the function that is calculating precision & recall in the metrics section. So you're saying there is an error in how this function is working? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Well, no I am not sure now, because these are standard functions, also current keras has in-built prec and recall support, ```metrics=[keras.metrics.Precision(), keras.metrics.Recall()])```,  a similar [ques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425041/text-classification-high-accuracy-low-recall-and-low-precision) was asked but not answered. Maybe the comment section can help.

My [mathematical identity](https://qr.ae/pN2u3K)

Comment: can you use ```metrics=[keras.metrics.Precision(), keras.metrics.Recall()])`` instead of keras_metrics and get back with results?

Comment: When I change it to that code you mentioned I get an error "ValueError: Shapes (None, 2, 1) and (None, 1, 1) are incompatible", this was why I used an alternate method to begin with. I don't receive any error when I run the code as described originally.

Comment: Did you try ```ac_model_1b.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adamax', 
                 metrics=['accuracy', keras.metrics.Precision(), keras.metrics.Recall()])
```? Also are you using tf.keras or keras?

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried. I just imported keras itself

Comment: Can you print the whole error? ```"ValueError: Shapes (None, 2, 1) and (None, 1, 1) are incompatible"``` I want to see where that error is coming from.

Comment: I edited the question with the error code as it was too long to comment. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220270/discussion-between-sayan-dey-and-ian-murray).